# Prove a map injective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

For $a \in \mathbb N$ and $a \ge 3$ how to prove that the map: $f:\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ $$f(S) = \sum_{n \in S} a^{-n}$$

is injective?

**NOTE** please don't give hints

thanks.

I know why it is true intuitively but I can't put together a proof

Comment: Why don't you want hints? It sounds like you want to outsource your homework...

Comment: @Stefan I'm self-studying. please don't prejudge

Comment: a should be greater than 3.

Comment: @madmatician I'm not judging - I'm expressing my confusion about your explicit claim not to be provided with any hints. Furthermore, I'm also telling you which impression I get from that so that you can fix this issue and justify your (strange) request.

Answer (score 1):

It is not injective for $a=2$. Take $S=\{n\geq 2\}$ and $T=\{1\}$.
Then
$$f(S)=\sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{1}{2^{n}}=\frac{1}{2}=f(T).$$

On the other hand if $a>2$ the map $f$ is injective.

Infact if $S\not= T$ then let $m=\min((S\setminus T)\cup (T\setminus S))$ (the set $(S\setminus T)\cup (T\setminus S)$ is non-empty!).

If $m\in S$ (the other case is similar) then $a>2$ implies that
$$f(S)-\sum_{n \in S\cap T, n<m} \frac{1}{a^{n}}\geq\frac{1}{a^m}>\frac{1/a^{m}}{a-1}=\frac{1/a^{m+1}}{1-1/a}=\sum_{n\geq m+1}\frac{1}{a^n}\geq f(T)-\sum_{n \in S\cap T,n<m} \frac{1}{a^{n}}.$$